# Pandas Colormap - Changing line color

Tags: pandas, matplotlib, colormap

All I want to do is change the colour of my plots to different shades of the original colour I specify. The colormap I have in mind is 'Reds' from the matplotlib documentation.

For example, I have:

```
dfs2.plot(kind='line', color='red')
dfs3.plot(kind='line', color='orange')
```

But I want the second line to be a lighter red.

Any ideas? I'm fairly new.

Comment: What are `dfs2` and `dfs3`? Can you provide a [mcve]?

Comment: In this case e.g. `dfs2.plot(kind='line', color=plt.get_cmap("Reds")(0.5))`.